# Pandas overwriting different data frame when adding new column

Tags: python, pandas

All I want to do is make two data frames (A and B) based off of one original data frame. Then I want to add a new column to each data frame "LABEL" and have each row in that data frame = AVN_DEL_1_A or AVN_DEL_1_B relative to data frame name... Simple.. WTF is going on? why is modifying dataframeA messing up dataframeB.

```
    track
  CHROMOSOME     START       END
7       chr1  56365453  56369289
trackA = track
trackA.head()
  CHROMOSOME     START       END
7       chr1  56365453  56369289
trackA.assign(LABEL = str("AVN_DEL_" + str(1) + "_A"))
  CHROMOSOME     START       END        LABEL
7       chr1  56365453  56369289  AVN_DEL_1_A
trackB = track
trackA.head()
  CHROMOSOME     START       END
7       chr1  56365453  56369289
```

Comment: You should add copy trackB = track.copy()

Comment: that fixed part of the issue. Also I was failing to set the assign method on trackA to a new variable. Thanks.

I.E. trackA = trackA.assign(LABEL = ("AVN_DEL_" + str(1) + "_A"))

Comment: You may need look at locals()

Comment: `.assign` doesn't modify a dataframe, it returns a new data frame, you need to do `trackA = trackA.assign(...)` or just `trackA['LABEL'] = 'AVN_DEL_{}_A'.format(1)`